# How to change server time as much as 1 hour in Linux?

Tags: linux, timezone, ubuntu-20.04

There is a thing in Iran, that on the new year, usually the official clock will be increased 1 hour. but in this new year (which was 4 days ago), we had not any change in the clock.

but I don't know why, the Linux `timedatectl` (as usual) has increased the time 1 hour. I mean, the official clock is 2pm now, but in the linux it's 3pm.

```
root@host:/home/me# date
Sun 26 Mar 2023 03:26:30 PM +430
root@host:/home/me#
```

In the terminal output above, that +4:30 should be +3:30

Noted that I've run command `timedatectl set-timezone Asia/Tehran` again, but nothing changed. Also, I've run command `date -d '+1 hour'`. But it just returns a modified data-time .. not chaining the date-time of the server permanently.

Any idea how can I fix it?

Comment: Maybe your OS is not up to date. I use Debian and my timezone is set to Asia/Tehran and I have no problem and the time hasn't changed.

Comment: @sd70 I see .. any idea how can I update the OS?

Comment: Just use the following command: `apt update && apt upgrade`

Answer (score 1):

Obviously the daylight saving in Iran has been abandoned:
[worlddata.info - Iran](https://www.worlddata.info/asia/iran/timezones.php)

So your computer switched to IRDT, that is not existent anymore.

To update your data the iana.org can help: [iana.org time-zones](https://data.iana.org/time-zones/tz-link.html)

They provide the current tzdata files and scripts to handle the `zone.tab`:

```
wget https://www.iana.org/time-zones/repository/tzdata-latest.tar.gz
```

.... just in case the update of your Debian (as suggested by *sd70*) does not help.